# Grunt: Access YAML symbols in external file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yaml

I am trying to reference values from an external YAML file in my Gruntfile. I am reading the YAML with no problems using:

```
external_config: grunt.file.readYAML('config.yml')
```

My `config.yml` file contains the following:

```
foo: abc
:bar: def
```

I can use `<% %>` templating to get the value for `foo` in my Gruntfile just fine:

```
foo: '<%= external_config.foo %>'
```

But I can't seem to be able to get the value for `:bar`. I have learned the colon in front of the key denotes a symbol ([Colon in the front: YAML syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673857/colon-in-the-front-yaml-syntax)), but I have no idea how to get to its value from my Gruntfile.

```
bar: '<%= external_config.bar %>' // doesn't work
bar: '<%= external_config.:bar %>' // throws error "Unexpected token :"
bar: '<%= external_config.\:bar %>' // throws error "Unexpected token :"
```

I cannot modify the YAML file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: 1) What happens if you run grunt with `--verbose`? 2) Have you tried `external_config[':bar']`?

Comment: @mparnisari `external_config[':bar']` worked like a charm — thank you! Please add it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `external_config[':bar']` within the template.

Explanation: Grunt is just plain JavaScript, so you can access an object's properties by using the bracket notation.